# How to return the proper object type after deserialization?

Tags: java, serialization

I'm currently working on a serialization class for my code library.
This is to avoid having to write the same code over and over again.

Because this is part of my code library i never know what kind of object class i'm deserializing.
I was wondering of anyone could update my code to have the return value be the kind of class i provide in the method variable.
Hope it makes sense :)

```
public static Object deserializeObject(File serializedFile) {
    Object returnObject;
    if (!serializedFile.exists() || !serializedFile.canRead()) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        //use buffering
        InputStream file = new FileInputStream(serializedFile);
        InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(file);
        ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream(buffer);
        try {
            //deserialize the List
            returnObject = input.readObject();
        } finally {
            input.close();
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return returnObject;
}
```

Comment: Could it be achieved by casting the de-serialized object to appropriate class? Are you doing some specific operation on the de-serialized object? Return type of function has to be defined before compile time it can't be decided at runtime. But if you tell more about the problem, I'm sure there must be some way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare the method like this:

```
public static <T> T deserializeObject(File serializedFile, Class<T> type) {
    ...
    return (T) returnObject; // Or return type.cast(returnObject);
}
```

When you are calling the method, you could then use

```
MyObj myObj = deserializeObject(file, MyObj.class);
```

Comment: Makes sense but why not just use `MyObj myObj = (MyObj) deserialize(file)`

Comment: @ShivamKalra Yep, that's how I'd do it, but the OP asked: "I was wondering of anyone could update my code to have the return value be the kind of class i provide in the method variable" so I'm assuming he wants to pass in the class to do something more...

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to return the class of the deserialized object?
if so you could just do

```
return returnObject.getClass().getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the instanceof check to see what type of object you are passing in, then based on that case it to the appropriate type.

```
  public static void doSomething(Animal aAnimal){
    if (aAnimal instanceof Fish){
      Fish fish = (Fish)aAnimal;
      fish.swim();
    }
    else if (aAnimal instanceof Spider){
      Spider spider = (Spider)aAnimal;
      spider.crawl();
    }
  }
```

You could also add another parameter as input to your method and pass in the class of object you want to deserialize. Normally I would name it something like Class clazz.

```
public static Object deserializeObject(Class clazz, File serializedFile)
```

If you pass the type of class in, you could cast your object using that value.